# DevExpress Winform - How to compare data between two gridcontrol on multiple key field

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I have 2 `gridControl` and I wanna change background of cells (rows) that different between 2 `gridControl` with primary key is multiple field set by user.
Any solution for this problem?

[See this example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0U2I.png)

In this two query, key field is col1, col2, col3 and col4. Different in col6 and I want to highlight cell that have different value.

This is my current code for RowCellStyle event

```
 private void gvQuery1_RowCellStyle(object sender, RowCellStyleEventArgs e)
 {
     if (gcQuery2.DataSource == null || lsKey == null || lsKey.Count <= 0)
         return;

     List<object> id = new List<object>();
     foreach (KeyObject key in lsKey)
     {
         id.Add((sender as GridView).GetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle, key.key1[1].ToString()));
     }
     for (int i = 0; i < gvQuery2.RowCount; i++)
     {
         int rowHandle = gvQuery2.GetVisibleRowHandle(i);
         bool flgEqual = true;

         for (int j = 0; j < lsKey.Count; j++)
         {
             object v = gvQuery2.GetRowCellValue(rowHandle, gvQuery2.VisibleColumns[int.Parse(lsKey[j].key2[0].ToString())]);
             if (id[j] == null && v == null)
                 continue;
             if (!id[j].GetType().Equals(v.GetType()) || !id[j].ToString().Equals(v.ToString()))
             {
                 flgEqual = false;
                 break;
             }
         }

         if (flgEqual)
         {
             for (int k = 0; k < (sender as GridView).Columns.Count; k++)
             {
                 if (!(sender as GridView).GetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle, (sender as GridView).Columns[k].FieldName).ToString()
                     .Equals(gvQuery2.GetRowCellValue(rowHandle, (sender as GridView).Columns[k].FieldName).ToString()))
                 {
                     if (e.Column.FieldName.Equals((sender as GridView).Columns[k].FieldName))
                         e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Orange;
                 }
             }

             break;
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Show effort and where is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `GridView.RowCellStyle` event, which enables appearance settings of individual cells to be changed

Please refer this site for your reference 
https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q520842

```
 void gridView1_RowCellStyle(object sender, RowCellStyleEventArgs e)
 {
   GridView currentView = sender as GridView;
   if (e.Column.FieldName == "Customer")
   {
     bool value = Convert.ToBoolean(currentView.GetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle, "Flag_Customer"));
     if (value)
        e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Red;
   }
    if (e.Column.FieldName == "Vendor")
    {
      bool value = Convert.ToBoolean(currentView.GetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle, "Flat_Vendor"));
      if (value)
        e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't change background color of second gridControl with this (or i don't know how to do that)

Comment: both are Devexpress COntrols

Comment: did u downloaded the sample example which is attached in the site , in that it is works , put same for both if again u r getting same error please post your code u r using

Comment: if the version is old that  downloaded convert the downloaded sample project to your version by using convertor in the Devexpress

Comment: I tried but still can't change color for both `gridControl`
I was added current code, please review it. Thanks

Comment: i had put a updated code u can refer this code inside your code in the loop statement

Comment: i think from the code u need that when i select one row that row in the 2grid show the different color which replies the same data in the 2nd grid

Comment: Same as bottom answer, key is not only 1 column, so i can't compare data with only 1 column

Comment: didn't understand

Comment: In my database, this table has multiple primary key (col1, col2, col3, col4)
If i want to compare data from 2 differrent query in this table, i must identify it by data in (col1, col2, col3, col4)

Comment: put an alias name for the common primary key of both tables and check if this key is equal to the another grid key of that primary key , chenge the color of the cell

Comment: `put an alias name for the common primary key of both tables`  
Can you give me an example?

Comment: from the query u should bring a common primary key and keep that column hide in the two grids control and in the first grid row selected event. inside this event, put the id of the first selected event is matching with 2nd grid any row then change the color, hint: in the 2nd grid column u should be looped inside the first grid row selected event

Comment: I can't change the query, because query wrote by user too :'(

Comment: ok then u can take the common primary value form both gris and check with my above requirements

Comment: can u show the image of collection of both grid u loading

Comment: See my first post please, i had attached image

Answer (score 0):

**Refer this:** [Customizing Appearances of Individual Rows and Cells](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument758)

> You can implement your functionality using the
> [GridView.RowCellStyle](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_RowCellStyletopic.aspx) event. This event is fired for each cell in
> a Grid View and thus it has **Column** and **RowHandle** parameters
> that identify the cell being painted.

I assume that you have fixed number of records in both grid and also the order of the records are same. Then you can try to user same row handle to access the value from the both grid's MainView at RowCellStyle event as below:

```
 using DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid;
    // ... 
    private void gridView1_RowCellStyle(object sender, RowCellStyleEventArgs e) {
       GridView View = sender as GridView;
       GridView leftGridView = leftGrid.MainView as GridView; //It is up to you that which viewtype you have used.
       if(e.Column.FieldName == "Col5") {
          string srcVal= View.GetRowCellDisplayText(e.RowHandle, View.Columns["Col5"]); // You can use GetRowCellValue() method also to get the value from the cell.
          string leftGridVal= leftGridView .GetRowCellDisplayText(e.RowHandle, leftGridView .Columns["Col5"]);
          if(srcVal != leftGridVal) {
             e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.DeepSkyBlue;
             e.Appearance.BackColor2 = Color.LightCyan;
          }
       }
    }
```

Above code snippet is just like a sudo code to direct you to implement the functionality.. Handle this event on that Grid on which you want to color.. Remember to take care about the RowHandle, you have take care about the row index.

Hope this help..

Comment: The key for map relation between 2 `gridControl` is not only 1, it's multiple field set by user, so, i can't compare only by `if(e.Column.FieldName == "Col5")`

Comment: it is an example.. It is not impossible to compare multiple column values if are able to access these rows at once.